# vagrant-proxyconf "`split': bad URI" error on installing plugin for Vagrant

Tags: windows, proxy, vagrant

Note, I'm running this on a Windows Environment.

I'm working behind a corporate proxy, and trying to get the [vagrant-proxyconf](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf) plug-in working so the vagrant machines can be set up to work through a proxy. However, on executing `vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf` I got the following error:

```
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins, reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network issues. The error from Bundler is:

Could not fetch specs from http://gems.hashicorp.com/

Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gems.hashicorp.com/Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gems.hashicorp.com/
```

Figuring it was probably a proxy issue, I tried setting my environment variable:

`set HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy:port"`

After re-executing the plug-in install command, I got a different error:

```html
C:/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not
URI?): http://"http://username:password@proxy:port" (URI::InvalidURIError)
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:996:in `URI'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/vendor/net/
http/persistent.rb:908:in `proxy_from_env'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/vendor/net/
http/persistent.rb:858:in `proxy='
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/vendor/net/
http/persistent.rb:528:in `initialize'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:
113:in `new'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:
113:in `connection'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:
103:in `initialize'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/source/ruby
gems.rb:262:in `new'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/source/ruby
gems.rb:262:in `block in remote_specs'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/source/ruby
gems.rb:262:in `map'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/source/ruby
gems.rb:262:in `remote_specs'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/source/ruby
gems.rb:202:in `fetch_specs'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/source/ruby
gems.rb:66:in `specs'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/definition.
rb:216:in `block (2 levels) in index'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/definition.
rb:213:in `each'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/definition.
rb:213:in `block in index'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:
in `build'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/definition.
rb:209:in `index'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/definition.
rb:203:in `resolve'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/definition.
rb:133:in `specs'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/definition.
rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/installer.r
b:76:in `run'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.6/lib/bundler/installer.r
b:15:in `install'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:
226:in `block in internal_install'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:
284:in `block in with_isolated_gem'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:
in `use_ui'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:
283:in `with_isolated_gem'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:
225:in `internal_install'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:
92:in `install'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/mana
ger.rb:62:in `block in install_plugin'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/mana
ger.rb:72:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/mana
ger.rb:72:in `install_plugin'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/plugin
/action/install_gem.rb:37:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/ward
en.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/buil
der.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runn
er.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.r
b:19:in `busy'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runn
er.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/plugin
/command/base.rb:14:in `action'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/plugin
/command/install.rb:32:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/plugin
/command/install.rb:31:in `each'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/plugin
/command/install.rb:31:in `execute'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/plugin
/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:i
n `execute'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment
.rb:292:in `cli'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:174:in `<ma
in>'
```

Note the error:
`C:/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in 'split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://"http://username:password@proxy:port" (URI::InvalidURIError) from C:/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in parse'`

Seems it's interpreting the environment variable incorrectly and having issues interpreting it? Anyone know how to address this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't probably even need the quotes (unless the password includes some funny characters). So you could just try:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:port
```

If you need the quotes, the correct form is:

```
set "HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:port"
```

Comment: Thanks from my side too, I had exactly the same issue. One question I ran the command in the bin folder of my Vagrant installation. Is that the only correct directory from which you need to run the command? Thanks

Comment: @innuendo the directory doesn't matter, as long as the variables are set for the shell session where you run `vagrant` commands.